# How to install vim on RedHat via commmandline

Tags: vim, installation, command-line-interface, redhat

I am running a RHEL 7.2 (Maipo) on an AWS instance with commandline access. To my greatest surprise, vim needs to be installed and as I am fairly new to RedHat, I was at a loss initially as to the easiest way to install it, so I am adding it below for future reference so beginners like myself can just crack on with it.

Comment: `vi` is preinstalled

Comment: @grabantot - Thanks a lot for the reminder, absolutely true. This is more for those of us who find vim adds a little more of life's niceties: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/biggest-differences-between-vim-and-vi

Comment: Even though the command `vim` doesn't exist, does `vi` invoke VIM? It seems to be the case for me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As root user issue the following command to install the vim editor on RedHat linux:

```
sudo yum install vim
```

Comment: so you answered your own question!

Comment: @RuncyOommen,  Apparently I am allowed to do so - and I thought I'll save folks some time. But do go ahead if there are other ways, it certainly helps me to learn.